# How to link my charts on dashboard to MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, morris.js

I need to produce a dashboard that shows three types of graphs. And since I'm really new to this and still learning, I have try several methods. I come across few solution but all of the graphs are hard-coded and can't be called from database.

Below is my source code:

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gsd");
$query = "SELECT * FROM emergency";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $chart_data .= "{ date:'".$row["date"]."', patient_seen_u:".$row["patient_seen_u"].", patient_seen_a:".$row["patient_seen_a"]."}, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>GOOD SERVICES DELIVERY</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Animation library for notifications   -->
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--  Light Bootstrap Table core CSS    -->
    <link href="css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--  CSS for Demo Purpose, don't include it in your project     -->
    <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="azure" data-image="assets/img/sidebar-5.jpg">

    <!--

        Tip 1: you can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="blue | azure | green | orange | red | purple"
        Tip 2: you can also add an image using data-image tag

    -->

        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
              <p> Hospital Tanah Merah</p>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="dashboard.html">
                        <i class=""></i>
                        <p>Arrival & Emergency</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="user.html">
                        <i class=""></i>
                        <p>Obstetrics & Gynecology</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="table.html">
                        <i class=""></i>
                        <p>Wad</p>
                    </a>
                </li>


            <li>
            <li> <a href="#pages-nav-list" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon-interface-windows"></i><span><p>Ortopedik & Medikal</p></span>
                <div class="arrow pull-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div></a>
              <ul id="pages-nav-list" class="collapse list-unstyled">
                <li> <a href="wad1.html"> Orthopedik & Medical </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Orthopedik</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Medical</a></li>
                    </a> </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="icons.html">
                        <i class=""></i>
                        <p>Pediatric</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="maps.html">
                        <i class=""></i>
                        <p>Mortuary</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bed Management System</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Log out</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="separator hidden-lg hidden-md"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <!-- Start of Charts-->

              <!-- bar charts group -->
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Bar Chart Group <small>Sessions</small></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content1">
                    <div id="graph_bar_group" style="width:100%; height:280px;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- /bar charts group -->

              <!-- bar charts group -->

              <!-- /bar charts group -->
            </div>

            </div>
  </div>

  <!-- End of Charts -->
  </div>
</div>
</body>

    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--  Checkbox, Radio & Switch Plugins -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-checkbox-radio-switch.js"></script>

    <!--  Charts Plugin -->
    <script src="js/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
    <script src="js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="../vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>

    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>

    <!-- morris.js -->
    <script src="../vendors/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="../build/js/custom.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris.js -->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Morris.Bar({
          element : 'graph_bar_group',
          data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
          xkey:'date',
          ykeys:['patient_seen_u','patient_seen_a'],
          labels:['Peratusan < 60 minit','Jumlah kes'],
          barRatio: 0,2,
          hideHover:'auto'
          resize: true
        });
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

As you can see, I use the existing dashboard and only alter it a bit. My problem is the graph that get produced doesn't call for the data in the database, instead showing the embedded graphs. The picture of the dashboard is as follows;

[image]

So what should I do, since if I do the graph on a separate page, the graph does appear on the page with the data inside my database. Any help and suggestion is deeply appreciated.

edit:

Since it's hard to understand my question, here is what I have in my database

```
CREATE TABLE `emergency` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `patient_seen_u` double NOT NULL,
  `patient_transfer_u` double NOT NULL,
  `patient_refer_u` double NOT NULL,
  `patient_seen_a` double NOT NULL,
  `patient_transfer_a` double NOT NULL,
  `patient_refer_a` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `emergency` (`id`, `date`, `patient_seen_u`, `patient_transfer_u`, `patient_refer_u`, `patient_seen_a`, `patient_transfer_a`, `patient_refer_a`) VALUES
(1, '2017-02-22', 13, 14, 17, 15, 16, 20),
(2, '2017-03-22', 12, 13, 11, 15, 15, 16),
(3, '2017-04-22', 10, 11, 9, 14, 13, 11),
(4, '2017-05-22', 9, 12, 11, 10, 15, 10),
(5, '2017-06-22', 10, 11, 12, 15, 14, 18);
```

However, the displayed graph doesn't contain the data from my database. How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any errors in the console? What do you mean by `the graph that get produced doesn't call for the data in the database, instead, showing the embedded graphs` ?

Comment: There's no error, but the graph that is shown on the page, is the original graph that I got from the template I used. It doesn't call for the data that I want from my database.

Comment: I don't see where you get data from your template in the code you provided. I only see `chart_data` coming from you database. So I don't really understand what your problem is.

Comment: That is the problem that I encounter, I can't seem to find where the data of the graph embedded on the template, but at the same time it doesn't call for my date from the database as well.

Comment: I already provide the data from my database, hope there's anyone who can give me guidance.

Comment: Validate that the div id where your chart is displayed on your page is really `graph_bar_group` with a browser tools. Then you can search everywhere in your project were this id is referenced: search `graph_bar_group` to identify where the div used to display your graph is used.